# PHP Form doesn't send data to database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm struggling for two days with this form issue. The form does everything that it has to, except for putting the data in mysql database.

I'm working in a Wordpress installation with Twitter Bootstrap.

Here's the form page:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" action="../process.php" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="email">E-Mail</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="voornaam">Voornaam</label>
        <input type="text" name="voornaam" class="form-control" id="voornaam" placeholder="Voornaam">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Schrijf me in!</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

And here's the process.php:

```
<?php
//get the form elements and store them in variables
$voornaam=$_POST["voornaam"];
$email=$_POST["email"];

//establish connection
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pasw","db"); //actual names in my code
//on connection failure, throw an error
if(!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: '. mysql_error());
    }

$sql="INSERT INTO 'mailclients' ( 'email' , 'voornaam' ) 
VALUES ( '$email','$voornaam' )";
mysql_query($con,$sql);

//Redirects to the specified page
header("Location: /nieuwsbrief-bedankt/");
?>
```

I hope someone can help me out here! Thanks in advance.

Thomas

Comment: try 'mailclients' to mailclients in your query also check you have exist post values for insert

Comment: `( 'email' , 'voornaam' ) ` these quotes should be backticks

Comment: and please please please don't use mysql_* functions. Use mysqli or pdo.

Comment: `mysql_*` Functions deprecated.Use `PDO` or `mysqli`.

Comment: Thx everyone the mysqli and the VALUES ('" . $email . "','" . $voornaam . "') solved it.

Comment: Btw downvoters, terribly sorry that I bored you. Never heard of mysqli before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct your syntax

```
$sql="INSERT INTO mailclients (email,voornaam) 
VALUES ( '$email','$voornaam' )";
```

*Normally i dont recommend W3school but the following link is good enough to remove your doubts:*
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: or maybe replace the single quotes with backticks

Comment: @om_deshpande yeah right but backticks are not mandatory so why take extra headche :)

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this,your mysql_connect is wrong never pass all four parameter in mysql connect if you want to use it then use it mysqli_connect

```
$voornaam=$_POST["voornaam"];
$email=$_POST["email"];

//establish connection
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pasw","db"); //actual names in my code
//on connection failure, throw an error
if(!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: '. mysql_error());
    }

$sql="INSERT INTO mailclients (email,voornaam) VALUES ( '$email','$voornaam' )";

mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Thanks